# Sandbox account constantly requires sign in

Tags: ios, swift, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

To test my in app purchases I am using a sandbox account. 
However after testing I am getting annoying alerts that says

```
 Sign-In Required 
Enter the password for .

[Environment Sandbox]
```

I have deleted the sandbox account which means I no-longer cannot sign in to the account.

Steps that I have taken (which did not work) 
・delete and reinstall the app
・sign out and sign in from my personal Apple ID
・Restored my iPhone using my backup
・Loop through SKPaymentTransaction and call finishTransaction

AppDelegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
・・・
        IAPManagerClear.shared.startObserving()

・・・
}
```

IAPClearViewController

```
class IAPClearViewController: UIViewController  {

    var products = [SKProduct]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        viewDidSetup()
    }

    func viewDidSetup() {
        IAPManagerClear.shared.getProducts { (result) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case .success(let products): self.buy(products: products)
                    case .failure(let error): print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func buy(products:[SKProduct] ){
        print(products[0])
        IAPManagerClear.shared.buy(product: products[0]) { (result) in

        }
    }
}
```

IAPManagerClear

```
class IAPManagerClear: NSObject {

    enum IAPManagerError: Error {
        case noProductIDsFound
        case noProductsFound
        case paymentWasCancelled
        case productRequestFailed
    }

    static let shared = IAPManagerClear()
    var onReceiveProductsHandler: ((Result<[SKProduct], IAPManagerError>) -> Void)?
    var onBuyProductHandler: ((Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void)?

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func getProducts(withHandler productsReceiveHandler: @escaping (_ result: Result<[SKProduct], IAPManagerError>) -> Void) {
        onReceiveProductsHandler = productsReceiveHandler
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(arrayLiteral: "com.appname.premium.subscription.monthly"))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }

    func startObserving() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }


    func stopObserving() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
    }

    func buy(product: SKProduct, withHandler handler: @escaping ((_ result: Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void)) {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

        // Keep the completion handler.
        onBuyProductHandler = handler
    }
}

extension IAPManagerClear: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("called")
        print(transactions)

//        let currentQueue : SKPaymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()
//        print(currentQueue)
//        print(currentQueue.transactions)

        for transaction in transactions {
            print(transaction.error ?? "")
            if transaction.transactionState == .failed{
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }
}


extension IAPManagerClear: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
           let products = response.products

           // Check if there are any products available.
           if products.count > 0 {
               // Call the following handler passing the received products.
               onReceiveProductsHandler?(.success(products))
           } else {
               // No products were found.
               onReceiveProductsHandler?(.failure(.noProductsFound))
           }
    }


}

extension IAPManagerClear.IAPManagerError: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .noProductIDsFound: return "No In-App Purchase product identifiers were found."
        case .noProductsFound: return "No In-App Purchases were found."
        case .productRequestFailed: return "Unable to fetch available In-App Purchase products at the moment."
        case .paymentWasCancelled: return "In-App Purchase process was cancelled."
        }
    }
}
```

SKPaymentTransactionObserver is not called when the alert appears.
Is there any one who managed to solve this?